# How can I get the value of a variable by address in c++?

Tags: c++, memory-access

For example, I have this code:

```cpp
char str[] = "hello!"; // this is a c-string
uintptr_t addr = _ADDRESSOF(str[0]); // this is an address

char* the_same_str; // there is the problem
```

How can I get the value located in the `addr` and store it to `the_same_str`?

Comment: `char* the_same_str = reinterpret_cast<char*>(addr);`

Comment: Igor, thank you, i`ll try it now